# Stop Excel Power Query from adding previously deleted rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a power query that pulls data from several Excel workbooks that are added daily into a folder.

These workbooks are generated automatically and I group it in a single table for analysis.

I have figured out that some rows mess up the reporting as they are not in the scope of my research and I have to remove them.

Thing is, every time I do it and refresh the query, they pop back up and I can’t do it manually every week as the table gets bigger and bigger.

I also can’t receive the workbooks without this unnecessary data so it’s one me to clean it up.

I have tried to modify the applied steps in the query, tried creating a macro and a VBA script but none of them work. Below is the VBA script:

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim i As Integer

    ' Loop through all rows in the sheet
    For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        ' Check if the row should be deleted
        If <your condition> Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

What other solutions do you think will help?

Comment: One comment: You probably want `i` to start at the max row and move down OR subtract 1 from it after you delete a row. Otherwise, you'll end up skipping over rows to be deleted if there are two in a row.

Comment: Add the steps to remove the rows to the query so that when it refreshes, those rows and other rows that meet the same criteria are removed when the data are loaded.

Comment: Asking "What other solutions..." is open ended and could lead to downvoting/closing your question. As @FlexYourData alludes, power query's M formula language is probably what you should learn/use.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to update your powerquery M formula. In the query steps, add a line like this:

```
let
    ...
    <PriorStepName> = ... ,
    NewStep = Table.SelectRows(<PriorStepName>, each <condition>)
in
    NewStep
```